# QWidget and setVisible() problem

Tags: qt, qwidget

I create a QWidget:

`m_widget = new QWidget(parent);` where parent is also a QWidget
then I set visible of m_widget to false 
`m_widget->setVisible(false);`

after that I need to show m_widget
`m_widget->setVisible(true);`
and this line of code hangs the application and only in release build on symbian platform

what's wrong? why does this code work in debug build?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with those lines of code. You will need to provide more code and context.

Comment: What is happening after setting it to false? What is the context of all this? Can you create a minimal example that still reproduces the problem?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this is a bug,
report over here,
https://bugreports.qt.io/

You can get better help by asking on, interest@qt-project.org